# What does the woman say before starts singing in a "Die Zauberflöte" scene?

Tags: listening-comprehension

In https://youtu.be/s7vJcUogrEI , what does the woman(mother) say before she starts singing?
To me it sounds like "Du wirst ihn törten und den mystiken sonnen Kreise mir überliefern"(You will kill him and provide me the mystic sun circle). Is this correct?

Comment: As seen in the answer below, the entire libretto can be found on-line. You may also be interested in [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDDDQ20aBEs) since you can turn on subtitles in German (also Italian and English). While I'm sure you can't have a problem with the music, using the opera to study German could be confusing since it was written over 200 years ago and the language has changed since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She says:

> [Du wirst ihn töten und den mächtigen Sonnenkreis mir überliefern](https://www.brilliantclassics.com/media/446102/94239-Mozart-Die-Zauberflote-Libretto.pdf).

Comment: In English (per Google): "You will kill him and hand over the mighty circle of the sun to me." I've forgotten exactly what the *Sonnenkreis* was, but the opera is full of magical artifacts; the flute was just one of them.

Comment: @RDBury It's not explained in detail in he opera what the exact capabilities of the *Sonnenkreis* are, but it seems to be Sarastro's main magical source of power. In many modern  stagings, the *Sonnenkreis* is not even mentioned (and replaced with the temple - who owns the temple is in power) as the scene that mentions it is considered overly long and often cut.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer and the comments!

Comment: Wo lebt Ihr, dass Ihr den Sonnenkreis nicht kennt - anderes Wort dafür: Corona. :)